# Glossaries: Groups not working

Tags: glossaries

I want to use the `sort=def` option for [glossaries](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) together with `style=alttreehypergroup`. However, as soon as I specify `sort=def`, the groups are not recognized any more.

**MWE:**

```
% arara: pdflatex: { action: nonstopmode, options: "-halt-on-error -file-line-error" }
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: { action: nonstopmode, options: "-halt-on-error -file-line-error" }
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% WORKING:
% \usepackage[style=alttreehypergroup, symbols, nolong, nosuper, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

% NOT WORKING:
\usepackage[sort=def, style=alttreehypergroup, symbols, nolong, nosuper, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\glssetwidest[1]{xxxx}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{firstgroup}{name={firstgroup}, description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{aaa}{name={aaa}, description=abcd, parent=firstgroup}

\newglossaryentry{secondgroup}{name={secondgroup}, description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{bbb}{name={bbb}, description=abcd, parent=secondgroup}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

**The output I want (and get without `sort=def`):**

[image: good]

**What I get with `sort=def`:**

[image: bad]

Is it my mistake or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature rather than a bug `;-)`. The `sort=def` option works by setting the `sort` key to a number rather than the value of the `name` key. If you look at the `.glo` file you will see this:

```
\glossaryentry{000001?\glossentry{firstgroup}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{000001?\glossentry{firstgroup}!000002?\subglossentry{1}{aaa}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{000003?\glossentry{secondgroup}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{000003?\glossentry{secondgroup}!000004?\subglossentry{1}{bbb}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
```

So now there's only one indexing group and that's the "Numbers" group. This method is the only way of getting `makeindex` to sort by definition. In fact, `makeindex` is simply being tricked into sorting by definition. From `makeindex`'s point of view it's simply using its usual sort algorithm.

Groups don't actually make much sense when you use `sort=def` or `sort=use` as there's no guarantee that the order will be restricted to groups. What if you defined terms in the order, say, `duck`, `parrot`, `dog`? You would end up with a `D` group, a `P` group and another `D` group.

However, if you're happy to take on the responsibility of ensuring that you don't have segmented groups like that, you can use what the manual refers to as "Option 1":

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[style=alttreehypergroup, nolong,nosuper,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\glssetwidest[1]{xxxx}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{firstgroup}{name={firstgroup},
description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{aaa}{name={aaa}, description=abcd,
parent=firstgroup}

\newglossaryentry{secondgroup}{name={secondgroup},
description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{bbb}{name={bbb}, description=abcd,
parent=secondgroup}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossary[sort=def]
\end{document}
```

Note that for this to work as you want it the `sort=def` must go in the optional argument of `\printnoidxglossary` not in the package option list.